# How to create rolling sum with missing dates in Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table with columns - `date`, `col_a`, `col_b`, `value`.

I am trying to do a rolling sum over `value` with a window of say 7.
The problem is we cannot guarantee that for all possible combinations of columns, we will have a sequential date series. So when calculating sum of last 7 days, it is possible that for that combination of columns, only 3 days (dates) are there.
The solution is that we can assume the missing dates to have a `value` column be 0.

I have tried a query that for a date gives creates a rolling sum table -

```
select col_a, col_b, sum(value), '2019-12-19' as foo
from schema_a.table_b
where to_date(event_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd')  < to_date('2019-12-26', 'yyyy-mm-dd') and to_date(event_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd')  > to_date('2019-12-19', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
group by col_a, col_b
```

I now have to do it for all unique dates from min to max.

Should I do the looping or is there a better way to handle such cases as it seems a fairly common use case.

In pandas, we do the imputation and rolling_sum quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GENERATE_DATES` and then left join your actual data to this table. Fill in any NULLS with 0's and compute the rolling sum.

Comment: There are multiple rows with the same date but different combinations of columns. The left join with such a table will not create rows with the missing dates with unique combination of columns.
Also, does `GENERATE_DATES` exist on Redshift as a default table or a function?

Comment: Redshift does not have generate_series (or generate_dates).  You will need to create the date list in SQL (recursive CTE is common for this).  If you could provide sample data (preferably in "insert into ... values" format) and the expected results this will make communicating your desired calculation clearer.